# How to use documentAttributes of CGPDFDocument

Tags: swift, macos, cgpdfdocument

According to [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/quartz/pdfdocument/1436054-documentattributes)
`CGPDFDocument` has a var called `documentAttributes`:

```
var documentAttributes: [AnyHashable : Any]? { get set }
```

I'm having trouble seeing how to use this to either get, or set document attributes of a PDF in Swift. Xcode doesn't offer it as an auto-completion following a dot, e.g. `myPDF.documentAttributes`.

How do you use it? I'm trying to get/set the document metadata such as Author, Creator, Subject.

Comment: It's a dictionary whose keys can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/quartz/pdfdocument/document_attribute_keys). You would do something like `let title = pdfDocument.documentAttributes[PDFDocumentTitleAttribute]`

Comment: I get "value of type 'CGPDFDocument' has no member 'documentAttributes".

Comment: The documentation in your link says it's available on OS X 10.12+. What version of OS X are you targeting?

Comment: Yes, I'm on Sierra 10.12.5. How do the get and set bits fit in?

Comment: New link for PDFDocumentAttribute is https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pdfkit/pdfdocumentattribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had a second look at the link you provided. It's not `CGPDFDocument` but `Quartz.PDFDocument`. Heres one way to access it:

```
let pdfDoc = PDFDocument(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: "/path/to/file.pdf"))!

if let attributes = pdfDoc.documentAttributes {
    let keys = attributes.keys              // the set of keys differ from file to file
    let firstKey = keys[keys.startIndex]    // get the first key, whatever the turns out to be
                                            // since Dictionaries are not ordered

    print("\(firstKey): \(attributes[firstKey]!)")
    print("Title: \(attributes["Title"])")
}
```

The list of keys differ from file to file so you need to check each one and deal with `nil` when the key is not available.

---

To change the attributes:

```
pdfDoc.documentAttributes?["Title"] = "Cheese"
pdfDoc.write(to: URL(fileURLWithPath: "/path/to/file.pdf")) // save the PDF file
```

Comment: Thank you. Why on earth are there two completely separate PDFDocument APIs? How ridiculous.

Comment: I can't see how to set a value, though. `attributes["Title"] = "Cheese"` doesn't work, nor does `updateValue`.

Comment: `attributes` contains a *copy* of `documentAttributes` so your statement had no effects on the PDF document. See my edited answer

Comment: I know this is old, but I see there is a PDFKit as well as PDFDocument still in Quartz as mentioned above.  Which one should be used to today?  I'm using XCode 11.6 and Swift 5.3.

Comment: I've struggled with creating a PDF recently and my conclusion is that the Core Graphics version existed first  and PDFKit was added after to simply it. The fact that PDFKit has properties pointing to Core Graphics leads me to believe that it is a wrapper and Core Graphics still does the work. Use PDFKit.